# WP: php function works in one place but not in others?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written the following code in my `functions.php` file, in order to format the price-tag found in a advanced custom field under each post:

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=price-tag', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format($value, 0, ',', '.');
  return $value."€";
}
```

This works perfectly in single posts - "5000" shows as "5.000€" etc.

But when looking anywhere else where more than one post is being shown: archives page, favourite posts page, widgets showing recent posts - basically anywhere apart of the single post, the function is not being applied, and the price-tags are just being shown unformatted.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Probably because the filter `acf/format_value/name=price-tag` is only applied at the single post page.

Comment: Okay - is there some way i can make it possible to be applied globally, or at least on pages as well apart from just posts?

Comment: You will have to check the templates that display the price, if necessary override them, and then apply the `acf/format_value/name=price-tag` filter to the price tag there.